# Растянуть li на всю ширину в ul с position: absolute

Tags: html, css

Имеется список.

При ховере на элементы списка происходит выделение:

[image: ховер]

Но если проскролить вправо, то получается вот такая ситуация:

[image: ситуация]

т.е. элемент не растянут на всю ширину.

Как сделать так чтобы элемент растягивался на всю ширину `ul` и выделение было до конца скролла?

```css
body {position: relative}
.dropdown-menu {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 177px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul{border: 1px solid red;}

.dropdown-menu li {
    position: relative;
}

ul li {list-style-type: none;}

ul li:hover {background:red}

ul li a{
  white-space:pre
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="selected">
            <a>Головное подразделение (654891238)</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>          vasya</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                    1</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                              2</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                        3</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                  4</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                            5</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                      6</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                7</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                          8</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                    9</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                              10</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                        11</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                  12</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                            13</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                      14</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                15</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                          16</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                    17</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                              18</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                        19</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  20</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                            21</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      22</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                23</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          24</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    25</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              26</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        27</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  28</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            29</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      30</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                31</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          32</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    33</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              34</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        35</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  36</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            37</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      38</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                39</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          40</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    41</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              42</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        43</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  44</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            45</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      46</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                47</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          48</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    49</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              50</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        51</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  52</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            53</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      54</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                55</a>
        </li><li>
            <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          56</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width: 100% !important;
}

#new{
display: relative;
max-width: 100%;
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 177px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
   display: block;
 max-height: 177px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.dropdown-menu li {
  position: relative;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li:hover {
  background: red
}
ul li a {
  white-space: pre
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="new">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" >
    <li class="selected">
      <a>Головное подразделение (654891238)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>          vasya</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                    1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                              2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                        3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                  4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                            5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                      6</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                7</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                          8</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                    9</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                              10</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                        11</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                  12</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                            13</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                      14</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                15</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                          16</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                    17</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                              18</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                        19</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                  20</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                            21</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      22</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                23</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          24</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    25</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              26</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        27</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  28</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            29</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      30</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                31</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          32</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    33</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              34</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        35</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  36</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            37</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      38</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                39</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          40</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    41</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              42</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        43</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  44</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            45</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      46</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                47</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          48</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    49</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              50</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        51</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  52</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            53</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      54</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                55</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          56</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте ul li a блочным элементом display:block;